# Keyboard issue with third level characters and shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I recently installed ubuntu (linux beginner) and I cannot access third level characters from my USB-connected keyboard.

I'm using a laptop workstation with two keyboards, both have German layout, therefore I switched the keyboard layout to German.

The built-in keyboard works fine, pressing "Alt-Gr" accesses third level characters like "@" and I can use shortcuts like "Ctrl+C".

On the USB-Keyboard (Perixx PX-1800) the third level characters are inaccessible **no matter what keyboard layout** I use. Shortcuts do not work. I had the same issue using linux mint.

Anybody knows how to fix that? Thank you in advance!